# How can I make my signals work and resolve this problem?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

Hi I'm trying to develop a website for an online store and I don't know why, for some reason, my models.py and signals.py are not coming into affect. When I ran the makemigrations command, it was ok, but when I ran the migrate command, it said "No migrations to apply". As a result, when I'm logging into my admin page, I'm getting an error, i.e `OperationalError at /admin/accounts/userstripe/ no such table: accounts_userstripe`

What can I do now? Can anyone please help me out?

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
import stripe


stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class UserStripe(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.stripe_id)
```

My `signals.py`:

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .models import UserStripe

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


def get_or_create_stripe(sender, user, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user.userstripe.stripe_id
        print user.UserStripe.stripe_id
    except UserStripe.DoesNotExist:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = str(user.email),
        )
        new_user_stripe = UserStripe.objects.create(
            user = user,
            stripe_id = customer.id,
            )
    except:
        pass


user_logged_in.connect(get_or_create_stripe)
```

Comment: Have you added your app name to **`INSTALLED_APPS`**?

Comment: Yes I have added it to installed apps

Comment: If you are not in production, drop your database and re-apply the migrations.

Comment: Do you mean delete my migration files and re_apply migrations?